# Write current date/time and number of files to a file

Tags: linux

I'm trying to set a cron job for a script which will append current date/time and number of files in a certain directory a file. I'm able to do this for only number of files:

```
ls | wc -l >> /root/log.txt
```

But how can I include the date/time in this entry?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$ echo "$(date) $(ls -1 | wc -l)" >> /root/log.txt
```